# Invalidate session for all users in playframework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

We are using play framework 2.1.4
Changing the `application.secret` in `application.config` followed by a server restart should ideally invalidate sessions for all the users.

But it seems to have no effect whatsoever and all the logged in users continue to be logged in.

Is my understanding that `application.secret` is used to validate the correctness of Session parameters and hence validate an user session is incorrect?

Is their any other way of invalidating all the logged in users' sessions?

Comment: According to the documentation, you seem to be right. Can you make sure the application.secret is not overwritten by a command line parameter, etc?

Comment: Thanks @Peanut I did check that already. It isn't used in the startup script or anywhere else!